# Symbolic Link Exists However Not Found At Project

Tags: php, laravel, storage, symlink, laravel-10

I have a laravel project and in this project, I am uploading some images like this:

```
public function storeImages(Request $request,Slider $slider)
    {
        // Get the uploaded file
        $image = $request->file('image');

        // Generate unique filename
        $filename = time() . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // Specify the directory to store the image
        $directory = 'upload/sliders/images/' . now()->year . '/' . now()->month;

        // Store the image in the specified directory
        $path = $image->storeAs($directory, $filename);

        // Save the image record in the database
        $sliderImage = new SliderImages([
            'slider_id' => $slider->id,
            'image_path' => $path,
        ]);
        $sliderImage->save();

        // Redirect or return a response as needed
        return redirect()->route('adm.sliders.images.info', ['slider'=>$slider->id,'image'=>$sliderImage->id]);
    }
```

And it works fine at localhost. But I don't know why it does not working at live server in production mode. (The image is being uploaded to storage path properly but the image is not shown since it does not exist at public directory)

Here is my `filesystems.php`:

```
<?php

return [

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'adm' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'root' => storage_path('app/adm'),
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        base_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

Now when I run **`php artisan storage:link`**, it returns:

**ERROR | The link already exists.**

However when I check the folder `public`, I see no such directory:

[image]

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try recreating the links using >>
rm public/storage
php artisan storage:link

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com I just told you the folder storage does not exist at all in public dir!

Answer (score 0):

have you maybe changed your links on the filesystems config? your `base_path('storage')` folder already exists, as that is the default storage folder. Of course you can't create a link on the same folder you are linking from. Try changing the link config into:

(and than run `php artisan storage:link`)

```php
'links' => [
  public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Comment: @pouya if this was helpful you can mark it as the answer